# How to fix Neovim gruvbox to work powershell

Tags: neovim

i am trying to set up my neovim config but i am having hard time with the plugins. For some reason colorscheme gruvbox does not work but all other plugins work. [my init.vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl4DS.png). I am using microsoft terminal to run powershell. Also my cursor is not displayed as block (both in normal and insert mode), i am not sure what is the issue here.

Comment: does it work if you type :colorscheme manually?

Comment: No, i have tried that :(

Comment: Have you tried Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'. Make sure to run :PlugInstall

Comment: Here it is https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl4DS.png . It doesn't work

Comment: Read my comment. You might want to add a bit more context if you want someone to help